# Is the dual category of an Abelian category also an Abelian category?

Tags: category-theory

[image]

Is the dual category of an Abelian category also an Abelian category?

In an Abelian category, does it have coproduct  of any pair of objects?

Answer (score 3):

Yes to both questions.

1. The axioms of abelian category are self dual.
2. An abelian category is in particular additive category, which admits binary products/coproducts.